# Firstname and lastname reverse on flight ticket for USA

Tags: air-travel, usa, bookings

I'm getting really worried as I realized my firstname and lastname were reversed on my flight tickets from Geneva (Switzerland) to Boston (USA). I tried to call the website from which I got the ticket (opodo UK), and the airline company (TAP Portugal): both are saying they can't change these names and ask me to see with each other. I tried 3 times each so I'm becoming crazy!!!! Finally Opodo told me they'll check with the company and will let me know in 3 days if it's possible or not.

My flight is leaving in 5 days so I really don't know what to do. Do I need to buy another ticket? It'll cost a lot but I'm thinking it's my last option... Is it really risky to travel with reversed firstname and lastname? If it won't be for the USA I'll me a bit more quiet, but it's not the case .

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Where exactly are the names reversed?  It is quite common to write the passenger name as LastName/FirstName on paper tickets, boarding passes, etickets, etc.